# GTest fixture when constructor takes parameters?

Tags: c++, googletest, armadillo

I have a simple example class. It has one data member, which is a std::vector of pointers to armadillo matrices. the constructor takes such a vector as the only argument. here's file `TClass.cpp`:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <vector>

class TClass {
    private: 
        std::vector<arma::mat * > mats;
    public:
        TClass(std::vector<arma::mat * > m_);
        arma::mat * GetM( int which ){ return( mats.at(which) );};

};

TClass::TClass(std::vector<arma::mat * > m_){
    mats = m_;
}
```

I want to construct a GTest fixture to test member function `GetM`. Here is what I have done:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h> 
#include "TClass.cpp"


class TClassTest : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
    int n;
    int m;
    std::vector<arma::mat * > M;

  virtual void SetUp() {
      n = 3;
      m = 2;
      arma::mat M1 =  arma::randu<arma::mat>(n,m);
      arma::mat M2 =  arma::randu<arma::mat>(n,m);
      M.push_back( &M1);
      M.push_back( &M2);
  }

  // virtual void TearDown() {}

  // initiate a TClass object
  TClass T(M);
};

// my test
TEST_F(TClassTest, CanGetM1){

    EXPECT_EQ( T.GetM(0), M.at(0) );

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I compile this with `g++ TClassTest.cpp -o tclass -larmadillo`. It tells me that `TClassTest.cpp:24: error: ‘M’ is not a type`. I dont' understand why I cannot construct the TClass object in the fixture definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object T cannot be initialized in the declaration of class `TClassTest`.  Have you been writing Java lately? ;-)

To initialize it, you can do something like this:

```
class TClassTest : public ::testing::Test {
  // ... (rest of code is fine as is)
  virtual void SetUp() {
    // ...
    T = new TClass(M);
  }

  virtual void TearDown() { delete T; }

  TClass *T;
};
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunately, doesnt work. i get: `TClassTest.cpp:27: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
TClassTest.cpp: In constructor ‘TClassTest::TClassTest()’:
TClassTest.cpp:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘TClass::TClass()’
TClass.cpp:16: note: candidates are: TClass::TClass(std::vector<arma::mat*, std::allocator<arma::mat*> >)`

Comment: just to make sure I understand: you use the default constructor in the TClassTest definition, `TClass T`. then you declare a constructor for that fixture that takes `M` as a paramter. right?

Comment: My bad.  Serves me right for trying to compile your example without the armadillo code.  The problem is that `TClassTest::T` has to get initialized and you can't do that in its declaration in `TClassTest`.  You could do that at the end of your `SetUp()` function, though, if you make T a pointer and write `T = new TClass(M);`.  Don't forget to delete T in the `TearDown()` function.

Comment: YES! this is awesome! thanks a ton! you've got no idea how long i've been struggling with this! :-) [and I wish I knew java!]

Comment: hey @Zymurgeek, you wouldn't have a sec to look at my related question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517174/googletest-fixture-for-blitz-class-with-arguments-in-constructor tried to apply this solution to a similar problem, but failed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42951/discussion-between-zymurgeek-and-florian-oswald)

Comment: Feel like I'm missing something: why can't you initialize `T` in `TClassTest`? I've been using constructor initializer lists, eg `T t {M};` and things have been fine. Is there some qualitative difference between these two formulations that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @dwanderson, C++ lets you declare but not initialize variables in a class declaration.  Class variables can be initialized outside of the class declaration if they are static or in a constructor or constructor initializer list if they're non-static.  I think what might be confusing you is that C++ lets you define the constructor in the class declaration.