# GoogleTest Fixture for blitz++ class with arguments in constructor

Tags: c++, googletest, blitz++

I have got a question that is related to this one: [GTest fixture when constructor takes parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497095/gtest-fixture-when-constructor-takes-parameters). I that question I wanted to know how to set up a GTest fixture when the tested class takes a parameter for the constructor. I tried to replicate the answer for blitz++ instead of arma, and I fail. 
Any clues?

The test class:

```
#include <blitz/array.h>
#include <vector>

class TClass {
    private: 
        std::vector<blitz::Array<double,2> * > mats;
    public:
        TClass(std::vector<blitz::Array<double,2> * > m_);
        blitz::Array<double,2> * GetM( int which ){ return( mats.at(which) );};

};

TClass::TClass(std::vector<blitz::Array<double,2> * > m_){
    mats = m_;
}
```

The test:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h> // Include the google test framework
#include "TClass.cpp"


class TClassTest : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
    int n;
    int m;
    std::vector<blitz::Array<double,2> * > M;
  virtual void SetUp() {
      n = 3;
      m = 2;
      blitz::Array<double,2> M1(n,m);
      blitz::Array<double,2> M2(n,m);
      M.push_back( &M1);
      M.push_back( &M2);
      T = new TClass(M);
  }

  virtual void TearDown() {delete T;}

  TClass  *T;
};


TEST_F(TClassTest, CanGetM1){
    EXPECT_EQ( T->GetM(0), M.at(0) );   
}

TEST_F(TClassTest, CanSeeN){   
    EXPECT_EQ( 3, n );  
}

TEST_F(TClassTest, CanSeeM){   
    EXPECT_EQ( 3, (*M.at(0)).extent(blitz::firstDim) );   
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The final test fails with

```
TClassTest.cpp:43: Failure
Value of: (*M.at(0)).extent(1)
Actual: 32767
Expected: 3
```

i.e. it seems that M1 is not allocated? Or it's gone out of scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's gone out of scope, just before SetUp is finished. You probably want:

```
class TClassTest : public ::testing::Test 
{
  protected:
    int n;
    int m;
    std::vector<blitz::Array<double,2> * > M;
    virtual void SetUp() {
      n = 3;
      m = 2;
      M.push_back( new blitz::Array<double,2>(n,m) );
      M.push_back( new blitz::Array<double,2>(n,m) );
      T = new TClass(M);
    }
    virtual void TearDown()
    {  
       delete T;
       delete M[0];
       delete M[1];
    }
    TClass  *T;
};
```

Another thing is that you are not supposed to include cpp files. Rename them to `.h` or `.hpp`.